# Does require("./test.json") load the JSON file with compression in Azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure-webapps

I have a nodejs app deployed on an Azure web app with compression enabled. The app uses require() to load a JSON file that is stored in the root folder of the web app. When I open the web app, F12 doesn't show the JSON got sent. Since the JSON file is big, I want to see performance gain with compression. But I didn't even see the JSON file got sent over to my browser. Any clue?

Comment: why would importing a module on the server generate any network activity?

Comment: What happened when I open the site page on my client computer. Do you mean the server response to my client request has already processed require() to include the json?

Comment: The test.json file is in the same place as the script that requires it (whether on your own PC or in azure).  So the file is loaded with disk I/O, not network traffic.  If the test.json file isn't in the same place as the script that requires it, the script will abort.